# Pb during migration from Nexus v2.14.3 to v3.2.1

Tags: migration, nexus, sonatype

I'm trying to upgrade our Nexus 2.14.3 to 3.2.1.

After having stopped the migration of a repository (ABORT button), I cannot migrate anymore again : Nexus 3 cannot recover the list of the repositories of Nexus 2 and I've the following message : "Upgrade has been partially configured and needs to be reset to continue."

Any ideas ? How to reset to continue ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you'll need to start the migration over.

Shut down Nexus 3, remove the sonatype-work/nexus3 directory, and restart.

Shut down Nexus 2, remove sonatype-work/nexus/db/migrationagent, and restart.

Comment: Ok, I missed the stage on Nexus 2.
So, I always have the message but now Nexus 3 show me the list of the repositories of Nexus 2.
I will start again the migration.
Thank you.